# How to Generate Raw packets and send to over network in vc++

Tags: visual-c++, winpcap

hai..
     how to generate raw pockets and send to another system using winpcap in vc++.i had done capture packets(sniffer) using winpcap in vc++

kindly help me

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can send packets using WinPcap, it's part of its interface (the basic function is called pcap_sendpacket).

In order to generate packets, you can simply write the packets' bytes.

What type of packets do you want to send? I have some experience creating packets, but I did that in C# (If you want to do that in .NET, you can create and send packets easily using [Pcap.Net](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com)).